# Whats Reliable Burst Protocol(RBP)?

Tags: protocol

I couldn't find much details about this protocol than an IEEE paper which I couldn't download. Any quick comments on this?

Comment: If its 7 years old and not even has a wikipedia article, it doesn't seem to be game changing...

Comment: Why would you care about some unknown, unpopular, seemingly theoretical only protocol?

Comment: There was a discussion about this among my peer group. So I just got curious. I wanted to know the use cases and if it holds some values in real sense, or its just another fancy name.

Comment: Guess you'll have to pay for the paper and read it, from the lack of any other references I'm guessing nobody's ever implemented it.